# Compare two lists and take lowest distance of compared items

Tags: python

I have two list.
One is nested and one I want to compare with the items of the nested list.

This is the nested list:

```
relevant_raw = [['1', 'Katharinenstr.', 'FaUobstr.', 'u,Wilhelmsplatz', 'Nordseite', 'I\n'], ['2', 'i', 'Iakobstr.', 'Katharinenstr.u.Haupt-', 'Gesamtbild', '1\n'], ['3', 'Katharinenstr.', 'Silhelrnsplatz', 'u.Jakobskr,', 'Nordseite', 'I\n'], ['4', 'ilhelmsplatz', '|', 'Katharinen-u.Hauptstätterstr,', 'Nordostseite', 'I\n'], ['5', 'jHauptstätterstr,', 'N', 'r', '.', '1', '4', 'u.', 'Chrlstosstr.', 'Wilhelmsplatz', 'Nordwest-', 'I\n'], ['6', '"', 'von', 'Wilhelmsplatz', 'nach', 'Tüdwiesten', 'I\n'], ['7', 'Wilhelmsplatz', 'alter', 'Marktbrunnen,', 'SUdwestjseite', 'I\n'], ['9', 'Schlosscrstr.', 'Einblick', 'von', 'Wilhelms^latz', 'I\n'], ['11', ';', '"', ':', 'Wilhelmsplatz', '«.Kaufhaus', ';', 'Nordwestseite', 'I\n'], ['.12', '!', 'Torftr.', '[Einblick', 'v.Hauptstätterstr.', '|', 'I\n'], ['14', '"', 'iNr.34', 'und', 'Brückenstr.', '"', 'I\n'], ['16', 'I', 'Hauptstätterstr.', ';', "Hs.i'ir.24", 'und', 'Hs.Nr.2', '|', 'Nordwestseite', 'I\n'], ['18', 'I', 'Hauptstätterftr.Ö', 'Einblick', 'Marktstr.', 'I\n'], ['IHolzstr.', 'Wagnerstr.u.Danziger', 'Frei-', 'Nordwestseite', 'j\n'], ['20', 'IHolzstr.', 'Haupt-', 'Blick', 'nach', 'SUdwesten', '1', 'I\n'], ['21', 'Rosenstr.', 'Holz-u.Untere', 'Bach', 'Str.', 'Südseite', '|\n'], ['22', 'Holzstr.2', 'u.', '|', 'Lederstr.', 'Nordseite', 'I\n'], ['24', 'Holzstr.', '|', 'Danziger', 'Freiheit', 'und', 'Kauf-', 'NordwestseiteM;', '*', 'I\n'], ['28', 'IRosenstr.', 'j', 'Eßlinger', '8', 'tr»u,', 'Holzstr.', '|\n'], ['I', '30', 'jEPlinget', 'Str.', 'Wagnerstr.u.', 'Leonhardsplatz', 'Westseite\n'], ['I', '31', 'bagnerstr.', 'Eßlinger-', 'und', 'Holzstr.', 'Südseite\n'], ['I', '32', 'Eßlinger', 'Str.', 'Wagnerstr.', 'u.', 'Hs.Nr.19', 'Nordwestseite\n'], ['I', '33', 'jLeonhardsplatz', '!Blick', 'gegen', 'Hauptstätterstr.', '|\n']]

This is the list I want to compare it with:
column_3_list = [ 'Nordostseite', 'Nordwestseite', 'Südwestseite', 'Südseite', 'Westseite']
```

In the end I want a list, with the same amount of items then the nested list has. 
It should compare all the items in the nested list and stop after it found the first which has a levenshtein distance below 5. But it should also check, if there are some words in the compare-list, that might have a lower distance and than append the item of the compared list with the lowest levenshtein to a empty list like `column_3`.
If it doesn't find anything in the nested list, it should just append `'x'` to the empty list.

I have no problem in getting the levenshtein and so on. I just can't find a solution to get the lowest-distance-word. And my else statement doesn't work also, so there is too much `'x'` around. I really hope somebody can help.
I also tried it with something like a dictionary (it is still in the code, but didn't workout)

```
column_3 =[]
compare_dict ={}
rest_3 =[]
for element in relevant_raw:
    found = False
    for item in element:
        for compare in column_3_list:
            if levenshtein(item, compare) < 5:
                #compare_dict.setdefault(item, []).append(compare)
                #compare_dict.setdefault(item, []).append(levenshtein(item,compare))
                column_3.append(item.replace(item, compare))
                rest_3.append(item)
                found = True
                break
            else: 
                rest_3.append('x')
                found = True
                break
            if found: break
print(column_3)
print(rest_3)
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish with this line, but this looks wrong: `column_3.append(item.replace(item, compare))`. Also `found` is always going to be true regardless of the Levenshtein distance, so there is no need for the `if found: break`.

Comment: I tried to replace  the word in the list for once. And I forgot that it is not necessary. Thanks for the advice. Any Idea for the rest? Can't find a solution so far